# Grails View disappeared in IntelliJ, how to get it back?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm very new to IntelliJ and Grails, and it looks like my Grails View in the tool windows sidebar disappeared, after I deleted a controller. I just cant find how to show it back, I need it because all my class files are shown in that view.

If you require more information please let me know.

thanks a lot in advance,
daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you still have `Grails` menu item in right-click menu on the project root? If not, press 'Add framework support...' in that menu and re-add Grails.

Comment: Grails is even not listed there. Only "Java EE", "JBoss", "Thymeleaf", "Spring" groups and several single entries. How to get "Grails" back to this list? My current version is IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.3.

Answer (score 8):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I recently had this problem and was able to solve it in the following way:

1. Click on `View` menu.
2. Hover on `Tool Windows` to let the submenu pop up.
3. Click on `Grails View`
4. The Grails view will now pop up, for me it popped up in the bottom section of the IDE. I wanted it back in the left so I right clicked the `Grails View` title and hovered over "Move to" then clicked on "left".

Hope this helps someone else. If Grails View is not available in the tool windows menu then it is most likely that Grails Framework support needs to be set up as Victor mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

For me the Grails menu item was available when right clicking on the project but the Grails Tool Window was gone. It was not listed in `View` -> `Tool Windows` like @paniclater suggested. I could restore it by doing a right click on the project and select `Grails` -> `Change SDK Version`. I just selected the Grails version I was already using and the view popped up.

Answer (score 2):

restart IDE after creating first time grails new project.
for me this works.

Comment: This works for me. Seems the intellij would recognize this project and do some view reloading after restarting.

Answer (score 2):

I started a Grails 3 project. The Grails View window was briefly visible in Intellij, and then disappeared. As of Intellij Ultimate 15:

"Note that the Grails View tool window is not supported for Grails 3. However, Grails actions are available in the Project View tool window. All artifact icons are changed to Grails icons."

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/getting-started-with-grails-3.html?origin=old_help

Comment: [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-grails3.html) is the updated link as of the current date.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had reactivated the Grails view with:

```
Tools->Grails->Synchronize grails settings
```