# No Grails View in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've just started with Grails. I made a new project, imported Grails 3.1.0. When I start new project Gradle View will appear, but it will then disappear as Gradle build is progressing. I also don't see Scaffolding toolbar either. I could create New -> Grails Domain Class, Controller...

I don't see Grails View in View -> Tool windows. Looking at same question asked: [Grails View disappeared in IntelliJ, how to get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532670/grails-view-disappeared-in-intellij-how-to-get-it-back)
but none of 4 answers work for me:

> Do you still have Grails menu item in right-click menu on the project root? If not, press 'Add framework support...' in that menu and re-add Grails.

I do have Grails menu with only one option: Run Target. Also under 'Add framework support' i don't see Grails.

> 1. Click on View menu.
> 2. Hover on Tool Windows to let the submenu pop up.
> 3. Click on Grails View
> 4. The Grails view will now pop up ...

I don't see Grails View there.

> restart IDE...

Tried restaring, doesn't do it

> For me the Grails menu item was available when right clicking on the project but the Grails Tool Window was gone. It was not listed in View -> Tool Windows like @paniclater suggested. I could restore it by doing a right click on the project and select Grails -> Change SDK Version. I just selected the Grails version I was already using and the view popped up.

This looked like my problem, but under under Grails all I have is Run Target.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ?

Comment: IntelliJ version: 15.0.1, Grails: 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails Tool window and scaffolding toolbar are not available for Grails 3 project yet. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145851

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.4.4, and it still doesn't work for me. IntelliJ used to be awesome with Grails.

Comment: @kevingreen have you tried http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2016/11/gails-goodness-enabling-grails-view-in.html ?

Comment: I just found out it's in the Project window, not the tools window. I'm a dumbass. I didn't know they moved it. I'm all set now.

Comment: @kevingreen We moved it for consistency with other frameworks.